# document.querySelector() is not applying style

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

Could someone point my mistake

[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Sathya_da/kLsohb7q/7/) ?

```
<p ng-controller="demo" class='bgColor'>
  This is dummy content
</p>

angular.module("app", [])

  .controller("demo", function($scope) {
    $scope.p = document.querySelector('.bgColor');

    var styles = {
      'background-color': 'red'
    };
    Object.assign($scope.p.style, styles);
  });
```

I'm trying to modify the class the property but am actually getting **TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null** in my Angular.js 1.x application. But when try in fiddle, I couldn't see the error but also style is not applied.

Thanks every one

Comment: How can I debug there? I don't see any output if I write console.log in the controller, nor any alert("foo").
Btw. it means your $scope.p is `null` and he did not find any element.

Comment: Are you using some kind of CSS pre/post processing? SCSS, CSS modules? Is Webpack or similar bundler involved in your compilation process? As @StefanRein pointed out, your `document.querySelector('.bgColor')` is not finding any matching element.

Comment: @ErnestoStifano we using less for handling styles. btw my scenario is that we are maintaining generic popmodal, some cases i want reduce the width of popup. so tired to do that as mentioned above

Comment: @Mr.Learner, Working here https://plnkr.co/edit/QU4r05n9rQprwyL9Ltxh?preview .. Might be the way calling script matters in your code,

Comment: @ManirajMurugan can you pls put it in fiddle.. for some reason i cannot access plunker in my network

Comment: @Mr.Learner, Sorry my bad I have given wron link.. Can you check here https://plnkr.co/edit/485FUBEcMvGTTzJT?preview

Comment: @ManirajMurugan i need your solution in jsFiddle. i am not able to open plnkr in network

Comment: @Mr.Learner, Here u go with fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/wtnosbkc/3/

Comment: @Mr.Learner am I missing something or your last jsFiddle seems to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the following working snippet. Also keep in mind that [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) discourages using controllers to manipulate the DOM.

```js
angular.module("app", [])

  .controller("demo", function($scope) {
    $scope.p = document.querySelector('.bgColor');

    Object.assign($scope.p.style, {
      'background-color': 'red'
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<p ng-app="app" ng-controller="demo" class="bgColor">
  This is dummy content
</p>
```

Comment: This is perfect..!!

Comment: btw what's the difference btwn `Object.assign($scope.p.style, {
      'background-color': 'red'
    });` and  `Object.assign($scope.p.style, styles);` nothing much right

Comment: @Mr.Learner theoretically should be more performant. In the practice, nothing. Just wanted to save some lines.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't accessing the element at the right time it seems. This is why it says "null".

```
var p = document.querySelector('.bgColor');
var styles = {
      'background-color': 'red'
    };
console.dir(p);
Object.assign(p.style, styles);
```

Putting this code after the controller part does work for me in chrome.

[image]

Comment: Rei, you're right, i've tried the same like before moving into Angular.Js $scope model but seems only working in JS alone